ThreadX NetX Duo multithreading
I'm wondering if there are any restrictions on using NetX Duo resources from multiple threads? E.g. assuming that an NX_IP object has been created using nx_ip_create (which looks to be thread safe as it disables interrupts when placing the create NX_IP object in the IP control block), can this object be passed to other API functions without explicit synchronization from the user application?
I'm investigating an issue where a call to nx_web_http_client_response_body_get sporadically fails with NX_SECURE_TLS_INVALID_STATE, which comes from the fact that the TLS socket seems to have been reset, and its type is NX_SECURE_TLS_SESSION_TYPE_NONE. Removing the other threads that share the network resources of the thread in question seems to resolve the issue, but I can't find anything in the NetX Duo documentation specifying whether multithreading is inherently supported.
